# Change background-image using React Hook

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm using React Hook to build my web app. I want to change the background image of a class, so that if the width of window < 376px it will display the "backgorund_mobile" and when it larger than 376px it will display the "backgound_desktop" but it doesn't work. How can I do that? Please help me. Thank you.

**Here is my code:**

Header.jsx

```
import React from "react"; 
import backgound_desktop from '../images/desktop/image-hero.jpg';

function Header(){
return(
    <div className="heading" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + backgound_desktop + ")"}}>
        //Some other codes
    </div>
)}
export default Header;
```

App.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import backgound_desktop from '../images/desktop/image-hero.jpg';
import backgorund_mobile from "../images/mobile/image-hero.jpg";

function App() {

  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = React.useState(window.innerWidth);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowResize = () => {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    }
  }, []);
  if (windowWidth < 376) {
    document.querySelector("heading").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backgorund_mobile + ")";
  };
  return (
    <div className = "container-fluid nopadding" >
    <Header / >
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Look into the useRef hook. I’m on mobile or would make an example.

Comment: Could you give me more details about this?

Comment: I guess you don’t need useRef. Look here. https://itnext.io/responsive-background-images-using-react-hooks-941af365ea1f

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
import React, {useState} from "react"; 
import backgound_desktop from './images/images-desk.webp';
import backgound_mobile from './images/images-phone.webp';

function Header(){

const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState(false) ;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handleWindowResize = () => {
            const bool =  window.innerWidth < 367 ? true : false;
            setMobile(bool) 
                
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
        return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
        }
    }, []);

    return(
        <div className="heading" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" +( isMobile? backgound_mobile : backgound_desktop) + ")", height: '400px'}}>
            //Some other codes
        </div>
    )

}


export default Header;
```

Comment: It does not work. It makes 2 backgroundImage disappear.

Comment: Now You can check

Comment: When I test it outside, it works but when I approve it to my code, it doesn't. I really don't know Why

Comment: Check carefully might be errors or missed something

Comment: It shows the desktop image but when it's < 376 it didn't change the mobile image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229320/discussion-between-man-of-action-and-cattttt).